# Change font size of chart (n3-charts/line-chart)

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, n3-charts

I am using https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart library to generate charts. Is it possible to change font size of axis labels? I could not find such option in official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this on the CSS would work

```
.tick text {
    font-size: 120%;
}
```

Edit: The appearance of many SVG elements can be configured using CSS, just inspect them in the browser and try modifying them.

Answer (score 2):

When the chart is generated it has it's own classes that you can take advantage of overwriting...  Here are all the axis for example:

```
// X-Axis Font
.x-axis {
    font-size: 120%;
}
// Left Y-Axis
.y-axis {
    font-size: 130%;
}
// Right Y-Axis
.y2-axis {
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

Hope that helps.